# OpenWRT: Unable to install package on USB stick

Tags: python, openwrt

I am unable to install python package on file system mounted on USB. It is trying to on overlay but not on usb. Could someone help me on this?

Please find details below.

**Version:**

```
root@LEDE:~# cat /etc/openwrt_release
DISTRIB_ID='LEDE'
DISTRIB_RELEASE='17.01.4'
DISTRIB_REVISION='r3560-79f57e422d'
DISTRIB_CODENAME='reboot'
DISTRIB_TARGET='ar71xx/generic'
DISTRIB_ARCH='mips_24kc'
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION='LEDE Reboot 17.01.4 r3560-79f57e422d'
DISTRIB_TAINTS='no-all'
```

**Filesytem**

```
root@LEDE:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 2.3M      2.3M         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    61.3M    560.0K     60.8M   1% /tmp
/dev/mtdblock3            4.4M      3.8M    632.0K  86% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay        4.4M      3.8M    632.0K  86% /
tmpfs                   512.0K         0    512.0K   0% /dev
/dev/sda1                29.2G     44.0M     27.7G   0% /mnt/usb
```

**OPKG configuration**

```
root@LEDE:~# cat /etc/opkg.conf
dest root /
dest ram /tmp
dest usb /mnt/usb
lists_dir ext /var/opkg-lists
option overlay_root /overlay
option check_signature 1
```

** Installing Python **

```
root@LEDE:~# opkg install -d usb python
Installing python (2.7.14-5) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.lede-project.org/releases/17.01.4/packages/mips_24kc/packages/python_2.7.14-5_mips_24kc.ipk
Installing python-codecs (2.7.14-5) to root...
Collected errors:
 * verify_pkg_installable: Only have 632kb available on filesystem /overlay, pkg python-codecs needs 837
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package python.
```